# Elasticsearch GET API for Shard Size

Tags: json, api, elasticsearch, sharding

With Elasticsearch 2.3.3, is there a way to get shard sizes using the GET API which returns JSON?

Currently I have found the following methods to get shard size, both of which are problematic:

1. `/_recovery` -> Responds with JSON and provides shard size BUT replica shards are reported as having "size_in_bytes" as 0 which is incorrect.
2. `/_cat/shards` -> Provides the correct/desired info BUT is NOT JSON and sizes are reported in non uniform units as strings (ex. 3.2KB, 4.9MB etc.).  This endpoint is more for visual consumption whereas I want to consume the response programmatically from an AJAX call.

I've done a lot of searching on Google / Elastic.com but have not found anything, but I would be very surprised if it is not available....

Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try the `_stats` API? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html

Comment: Hey Animesh, yes, _stats seems much more focused on "usage" statics ("query_cache", "request_cache", "searches", "get" etc.).  The only shard info I see is a very high level summary:  
_shards: {
total: 10,
successful: 5,
failed: 0
}, and this when asking for the index detail view /[INDEX_NAME]/_stats

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Animesh was right, the `_stats` API is the one that you want, but to get shard level stats, you must specify the [`level` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html):

```
curl -XGET host:9200/my-index/_stats?level=shards
```

The `level` can currently be set to any of:

- shards
- index (default)
- node

Comment: Thanks for the detail pickypg, did not see that one line (not even an example URL !!! hahaha) at the bottom of the documentation page but, my fault for not reading more carefully!  Animesh THANKS to you as well!!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get shards size is by the request:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v=true&format=JSON&bytes=b (mb, gb and etc.)
```

This is more convenient and better way to get information about shards, specially about size.

Elastic documentation: [elastic doc](https://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/cat-shards.html)

Comment: This is even more useful if you pass it through jq, so that you can get a listing of each shard.  You can then grep for specific nodes if needed:  curl -s -X GET 'localhost:9200_cat/shards?v=true&format=JSON&bytes=gb' | jq -c .[] | grep nodename