# How to get number of current open shards in elsticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't find where to get the number of current open shards.
I want to make monitoring to avoid cases like this:

```
this cluster currently has [999]/[1000] maximum shards open
```

I can get maximum limit - max_shards_per_node

```
$ curl -X GET "${ELK_HOST}/_cluster/settings?include_defaults=true&flat_settings=true&pretty" 2>/dev/null | grep cluster.max_shards_per_node
"cluster.max_shards_per_node" : "1000",
$
```

But can't find out how to get number of the current open shards (999).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A very simple way to get this information is to call the [`_cat/shards`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html) API and count the number of lines using the `wc` shell command:

```
curl -s -XGET ${ELK_HOST}/_cat/shards | wc -l
```

That will yield a single number that represents the number of shards in your cluster.

Another option is to retrieve the cluster stats using JSON format, pipe the results into `jq` and then grab whatever you want, e.g. below I'm counting all STARTED shards:

```
curl -s -XGET ${ELK_HOST}/_cat/shards?format=json | jq ".[].state" | grep "STARTED" | wc -l
```

Yet another option is to query the [`_cluster/stats`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html) API:

```
curl -s -XGET ${ELK_HOST}/_cluster/stats?filter_path=indices.shards.total
```

That will return a JSON with the shard count

```
{
  "indices" : {
    "shards" : {
      "total" : 302
    }
  }
}
```

To my knowledge there is no single number that ES spits out from any API with the single number. To be sure of that, let's look at the source code.

1. The error is thrown from [`IndicesService.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/55d4581ee4cd16e5b9b3146caf6d0e68e372e6a4/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/indices/IndicesService.java#L1467-L1471)
2. To see how `currentOpenShards` is computed, we can then go to [`Metadata.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a9f351556f519e4f9b23e755a3e5da767512a66a/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/MetaData.java#L202-L208).

As you can see, the code is iterating over the index metadata that is retrieved from the cluster state, pretty much like running the following command and count the number of shards, but only for indices with `"state" : "open"`

```
GET _cluster/state?filter_path=metadata.indices.*.settings.index.number_of*,metadata.indices.*.state
```

From that evidence, we can pretty much be sure that the single number you're looking for is nowhere to be found, but needs to be computed by one of the methods I showed above. You're free to [open a feature request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues) if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to get one number - 999 ?

Comment: Yes, i know, but may be inside elasticsearch this single number already has been calculated...

Comment: second way is not equal first way.
on my ES (we must exclude empty line to get 999)  
  
`GET /_cat/shards | grep -v '^$' | wc -l`
    returns 999  

 `GET _cluster/stats?filter_path=indices.shards.total`
    returns  
`{"indices":{"shards":{"total":790}}}`
  
due second way don't count UNASSIGNED shards  
  
`GET /_cat/shards | grep -v '^$' | grep -v UNASSIGNED | wc -l`  
returns 790  

so `GET _cluster/stats?filter_path=indices.shards.total` returns shards only in STARTED state and don't suit for my case

Comment: So, the first way it is, then. But I'll leave both options for people who don't care about the difference

Comment: Yes, but `grep -v '^$' ` is needed for precise result. That's why it will be more convenient to have just one number from elasticsearch.

Comment: weird because I don't get any empty line before the number

Comment: I've added another option, which should better fit your use case

Comment: it's one more argument to get just one number instead of bulk of text with extra processing

Comment: It's not bulk of text, it's a structured JSON reponse, parsed with jq, which is quite different. The one number you expect is pretty specific to your use case anyway.

Comment: You realize that your use case is pretty specific and ES cannot spit out numbers that fit all possible use cases ? It's not clear what you mean exactly by "open shard", is that only STARTED ones? STARTED + UNASSIGNED?

Comment: it is specific, but not very specific. This is pretty common problem and monitoring this current/max ratio (or just number of free available shards) rather useful

Comment: so common, that in ~10 years that I've been using ES, I've never felt the need to get that number :-)

Comment: but please answer my question, what do you mean by open shards ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198734/discussion-between-dmitry-perfilyev-and-val).

Comment: I do see the api `_cluster/health` which [surfaces](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html) all 4 metrics: `active_shards`, `relocating_shards`, `unassigned_shards` and `initializing_shards`... So we can possibly get the total open shards by summing them all up ?
Are all these mutually exclusive ?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:** Seems that your elastic cluster number of shards per node are getting limited.

**Solution:**
Verify the number of shards per node in your configuration and increase it using elastic API.

For getting the number of shards - use `_cluster/stats` API:

```
curl -s -XGET 'localhost/_cluster/stats?filter_path=indices.shards.total'
```

From **[elastic docs:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-stats.html)**

> The Cluster Stats API allows to retrieve statistics from a cluster
>   wide perspective. The API returns basic index metrics (shard numbers,
>   store size, memory usage) and information about the current nodes that
>   form the cluster (number, roles, os, jvm versions, memory usage, cpu
>   and installed plugins).

For updating number of shards (increasing/decreasing), use -  `_cluster/settings` api:

**For example:**

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d '{ "persistent" : {"cluster.max_shards_per_node" : 5000}}'
```

From **[elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html)**:

> With specifications in the request body, this API call can update
>   cluster settings. Updates to settings can be persistent, meaning they
>   apply across restarts, or transient, where they don’t survive a full
>   cluster restart.
>
> You can reset persistent or transient settings by assigning a null
>   value. If a transient setting is reset, the first one of these values
>   that is defined is applied:
>
> the persistent setting the setting in the configuration file the
>   default value. The order of precedence for cluster settings is:
>
> transient cluster settings persistent cluster settings settings in the
>   elasticsearch.yml configuration file. It’s best to set all
>   cluster-wide settings with the settings API and use the
>   elasticsearch.yml file only for local configurations. This way you can
>   be sure that the setting is the same on all nodes. If, on the other
>   hand, you define different settings on different nodes by accident
>   using the configuration file, it is very difficult to notice these
>   discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -s '127.1:9200/_cat/indices' | awk '{ if ($2 == "open") C+=$5*$6} END {print C}'
```

Comment: Although your answer seems to work fine, please add some more comments, example or documentation to make it better and more useful

Comment: at last, an `awk` mate!! Thank you for this :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $5+$6?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

GET `/_stats?level=cluster&filter_path=_shards.total`

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108448/4271117