# Filter the Elasticsearch cat API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I am using the `_cat` API of elasticsearch to get the various details of my elasticsearch cluster.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html

What I want is the ability to filter the response which I can't see in the documentation, for example output of `_cat/node?v` give the `node.role` which tells whether a node is `data` or `master` or `ingest` node and I want a way to filter the only `master` and `data` node in the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GET /_cat/master` instead of `_cat/nodes?v` to get the master node. Otherwise, you can use the `/_nodes/data:true` to get only data nodes

```
GET /_nodes/data:true
GET /_nodes/ingest:true
GET /_nodes/master:true
```

Comment: Note that you can also mix and match those filters, e.g. to get only data nodes that are not also master eligible: `GET /_nodes/data:true,master:false`

Comment: @Val exactly sir

Comment: @Val I was aware of nodes api but its very verbose hence want to filter the _cat/nodes API but this filter pattern doesnt work there :(

Comment: @java-dev then probably a combination of `_cat` + `jq` can do the trick: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57727356/4604579

Comment: @java-dev Also using the `_nodes` API you still have the `filter_path` attribute to filter out unneeded data and only get what you want

Comment: @Val I am using 1.x version and just did a quick search on `filter_path` and seems it not availabke even in 6.X :(

Comment: @Val JQ I can use but I prefer hitting the api in browser and postman so that I can share it with everybody and they dont hv to install JQ and use the relatively difficult `Jq`

Comment: @java-dev of course filter_path was there, even in 1.x: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/common-options.html#_response_filtering

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217055/discussion-between-java-dev-and-val).