# Get the filtered response in Elasticsearch cat APIs

Tags: elasticsearch

I am planning to get the information of all the primary shards in my ES cluster using _cat/shards API, but I don't see any option to get only the primary shards in the API response, I tried using `prirep:p` in the `h=index,store,prirep:p,index&v` but it didn't work also filter_path `filter_path=prirep:p`, is there is any way to filter the response in cat APIs of ES.

A sample response from ES

```
  791261 STARTED 563.3mb p      my_index
  789324 STARTED 563.2mb p      my_index
  791140 STARTED 563.1mb p      my_index
  789066 STARTED 562.8mb p      my_index
  789896 STARTED 562.7mb p      my_index
  791138 STARTED 562.2mb r      my_index
  789993 STARTED 562.2mb r      my_index
```

What I want is the below response, notice `r` (replica) shards are removed in response.

```
  791261 STARTED 563.3mb p      my_index
  789324 STARTED 563.2mb p      my_index
  791140 STARTED 563.1mb p      my_index
  789066 STARTED 562.8mb p      my_index
  789896 STARTED 562.7mb p      my_index
```

**I don't want to parse the response using jq, as shown [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57727356/10348758) because I would be implementing the code also and using the Get request in the browser itself.**

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to filter only primaries or replicas from the `_cat/shards` API. Also, as it's [not really a bug](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/69097), you should have posted that in the [discuss forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elastic-stack/81) instead ;-)

Comment: @Val I have raised a feature request under the `enhancement` label on Github. Posted the same on discuss forum as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know you are not interested in text processing. but I write this answer for who need it in `linux`.

```
curl -s "[elastic-ip]:9200/_cat/shards" |awk '$3=="p"'
```