# How to get all closed indices in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster and a few open and closed indexes inside.I want to get only closed indexes.

`GET _cat/indices?v&s=status`

this query getting all indices. I need a `GET _cat/indices?v&s=status:'close'` like this query.

Is this a possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in a way similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57727356/4604579) with grep to extract what you need

```
curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices | grep "close"
```

Comment: This method useful when working on terminal.This query also getting indices with "close" in their index name.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of closed indices using

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&s=status&expand_wildcards=closed
```

To know more about various other cat indices API parameters, refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html).

Comment: `expand_wildcards` is not for that purpose. The command you show also returns open indexes

Comment: @Val Can you please tell me what `expand_wildcards` is used for ? Because when I used the above url, I am getting the list of `closed` indices only

Comment: `expand_wildcards` is a hint of what indexes must be returned but **only if a wildcard is being used**, e.g. `GET _cat/indices/logs-*?expand_wildcards=closed` would only return closed indexes that start with `logs-`